# Javascript - Get an arm to point at elements being hovered over

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get a pivoted forearm to point at the links that are being hovered over.

It works on the actual website I'm making it on but the pointing isn't quite accurate (it's nearly there) - I think it's perhaps because the code is designed to pivot using the center of the image (ie an arrow) and I'm using CSS `transform-origin: center left;` to force it otherwise?

I've done a fair bit of research but I can't get past this last hurdle - How do I adjust the JS to make the pointing rotation accurate?

Here is the setup I'm using:

```js
$(function() {
  var img = $('.arrow');

  // Store clock wise degrees of all elements
  var clockwiseElemDegrees = {};
  var currentArrowAngle = 0;

  // Treat initial position of arrow as element 0
  var prevElem = '0';
  clockwiseElemDegrees['0'] = 0;

  if (img.length > 0) {

    var offset = img.offset();
    var imgX = offset.left + (img.width() / 2);
    var imgY = offset.top + (img.height() / 2);

    // Get element degrees
    $('.animation-trigger').each(function() {
      var element = $(this);
      var elementPosition = element.offset();
      var elementX = elementPosition.left + (element.width() / 2);
      var elementY = elementPosition.top + (element.height() / 2);

      var radians = Math.atan2(elementY - imgY, elementX - imgX);
      var degrees = radians * (180 / Math.PI);

      clockwiseElemDegrees[element.attr('elem')] = (degrees < 0) ? (degrees + 360) : degrees;
    });


    $('.animation-trigger').mouseenter(function(event) {

      // Check if arrow should be rotated clockwise
      var clockwiseDegreesForNextElem = clockwiseElemDegrees[$(this).attr('elem')];
      var clockwiseDegreesForPrevElem = clockwiseElemDegrees[prevElem];
      if (clockwiseDegreesForNextElem < clockwiseDegreesForPrevElem)
        clockwiseDegreesForNextElem += 360;

      var clockwiseRotationRequired = clockwiseDegreesForNextElem - clockwiseDegreesForPrevElem;

      if (clockwiseRotationRequired <= 180) {
        // Do clockwise rotation
        currentArrowAngle += clockwiseRotationRequired;
      } else {
        // Do anticlockwise rotation
        currentArrowAngle -= (360 - clockwiseRotationRequired);
      }

      prevElem = $(this).attr('elem');

      img.css('-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + currentArrowAngle + 'deg)')
        .css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + currentArrowAngle + 'deg)')
        .css('-o-transform', 'rotate(' + currentArrowAngle + 'deg)')
        .css('-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + currentArrowAngle + 'deg)');
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.scriptybits {
  width: 44%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
}

.wholepage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 95vh;
  position: relative;
}

.scriptcontainer {
  margin-left: 5% !important;
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 20vh;
  margin-left: 4px;
  width: 20vh;
  z-index: 5;
  -webkit-transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955);
  -moz-transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955);
  -o-transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955);
  transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955);
  transform-origin: center left;
}

.pageleft {
  display: inline-block;
}

.pageright {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  height: 90vh;
}

.menucontainer {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 43%;
  top: 9vh;
}

.leaningman {
  height: 86vh;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5vh;
}

.animation-trigger {
  border: 3px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: fit-content;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wholepage">
  <div class="scriptybits">
    <div class="pageleft" style="float:left; width:100%;">
      <div class="scriptcontainer" style="position:relative;">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/qxhaZOc.png" class="arrow">
        <img class="leaningman" src="https://i.imgur.com/L9zVucE.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="pageright">
      <div class="menucontainer">
        <a href="#" class="animation-trigger" elem="1">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#" class="animation-trigger" elem="2">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#" class="animation-trigger" elem="3">Link 3</a>
        <a href="#" class="animation-trigger" elem="4">Link 4</a>
        <a href="#" class="animation-trigger" elem="5">Link 5</a>
        <a href="#" class="animation-trigger" elem="6">Link 6</a>
        <a href="#" class="animation-trigger" elem="7">Link 7</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you create a JSFidlle or similar? Difficult to say without being able to test.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/r856kdtb/ I just added it into fiddle but it's not working - no clue why as I have the exact same code working on a live site

Comment: It works for me when I selected JQuery from the dropdown on JSFiddle. (default is pure JS). I'll have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are rotating the image from the center left, but you are calculating the rotation angle based on the position from the center both horizontally and vertically. Changing to

```
var imgX = offset.left
```

seems to improve it for me.